# SalesForce SOQL with lookup to create hierarchy string

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to create an SOQL query that looks to an employees report to position id and create a string that will concat the employees position id and the position id of his manager and concat the managers manager and continue this up the organization chart.

Example Data in Position__c:

```
Employee_Name     Position_ID      Reports_to_Position_ID
John Doe             123                    456
Billy Bob            456                    789
Jane Doe             789                    321
Harvey Sample        321                    654
```

John Doe's position id is 123, he reports to position 456. position 456 reports to 789 and so on.

Expected Result for John Doe reports_to_Hierarchy --> 123,456,789,321,654

Answer (score 1):

SOQL looks bit object-oriented, you use dots to go "up" the relationship. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm

The basic idea is

```
SELECT Name, Manager.Name, Manager.Manager.Name, Manager.Manager.Manager.Name
FROM User
```

Actual result depends if you have standard or custom object and what are the field names. You can go up to 5 levels (dots) away from your starting point.

Is the list flat just like that? You might need a helper lookup to "self" field on Position__c, call it "Parent__c", "Manager__c" or something. And you'd need to populate it during load (read about upsert and external ids?)

And then it'd be something like

```
SELECT PositionId__c, 
    Parent__r.PositionId__c, 
    Parent__r.Parent__r.PositionId__c, 
    Parent__r.Parent__r.Parent__r.PositionId__c
FROM Position__c
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this and getting an error INVALID_FIELD:
Parent__r.Id

Comment: On `Position__c` object, do you have a custom field of type "lookup" pointing to
 other `Position__c` records? Is the name of the field `Parent__c`? (and if the field is there but not really populated the query will compile but not return anything interesting) If all you have is a flat table you'll have hard time achieving this in pure SOQL but if you want I can come up with piece of Apex code to build the full hierarchy, you'd need to run it whenever data changes

Comment: SOQL can only do joins on proper foreign keys, you can't freestyle grab say Account.Name and compare it to Case.Subject and see what sticks.

Comment: I do not have access to the database information. I can only query the DB in workbench.  There is a formula field in the object that shows in salesforce reports but not when I query the table.  The formula is [Position ID]+',' +
[Generated Reports To Position].[Position ID]+',' +
[Generated Reports To Position].[Generated Reports To Position].[Position ID] and so on.  I am not sure how to write that in a query.

Comment: In Workbench go to "Standard & Custom objects" -> Position__c and see if you can find that field & it's API Name. You should be able to SELECT it. Or - find the exact api name of that `Generated Reports To Position` and try with `SELECT Name, GeneratedReportsToPosition__r.Name FROM Position__c` or something similar?